# how do you place code in a background thread

Tags: ios6, background-process

I am build an App that downloads a file and while that download is running I want to have a simple graphic that rotates like an animated Gif used to do in the old days.

So I have code in place to load this image, rotate this image a small amount, and then redisplay it.

I want this to continue rotation while the download is active.

I have looked at many pieces of code from the net but I think I got confused with too much information. Is there a simple way to do this.

I assume I have to have a method built to do the rotation and redisplay that I can loop to in this background process while I continue the download and then break out of the background task when the download ends.

What example code I have running now  follows:
for the download

```
        NSString *imagefile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://imoonaws.com/glold/data/%@/mid.png", Path];
    NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:imagefile];
    NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
    [data1 writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
```

and for the image rotation

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Icon.png"];

UIImage *rotatedImg = [image imageRotatedByDegrees:18];
[_image setImage:rotatedImg];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *imagefile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://imoonaws.com/glold/data/%@/mid.png", Path];
NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:imagefile];
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
```

Well, don't do that! That's synchronous downloading. Download asynchronously, as I explain in my book (http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch37.html#_http_requests).

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Icon.png"];
UIImage *rotatedImg = [image imageRotatedByDegrees:18];
[_image setImage:rotatedImg];
```

Don't do that either! To rotate an image view, don't change the image, which will require you to poll repeatedly on the main thread; just give it a rotation animation and let 'er go! Animation is explained in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html - I show you both how to do a rotation animation and how to repeat forever (and how to stop the animation when the time comes).

Answer (score 1):

> I assume I have to have a method built

Don't assume. Do the download and do the animation. If you are doing the download correctly, it *is* in the background. And if you are doing the animation correctly, it is in its own (different) thread. There will be no problem.

You do not say what is not working or whether anything is not working, and you don't show any code, so what more can be said? Did you have an actual question?

Comment: I was hoping for a simple example of how to split it into two tasks one in the background and one in the foreground.

Comment: And I'm telling you that if you download and animate properly it *is* two tasks (both in the background, actually).

Comment: Thanks for your time I will research it more thoroughly apparently I am NOT doing it right. Was sort of hoping for a generic structure to be shooting for. I will continue to struggle along for now

Comment: But, as I said, you do not *say* that it is not working, in your question, and you do not *show* what you are doing. Why not edit your question to do so? If what you are doing and what is happening are hidden behind a curtain, what kind of help can people give?

Comment: In terms of "generic structure", this is how to do a download http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch37.html#_http_requests and this is how to do animation http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html

Comment: I have added the the simple code snippets that actually do work and perfom the single functions I just need them to both work at the same time and the second one to loop. I looked at the links and it is exactly what I was looking for the code I have in place seems to be missing just a bit of code. not I can continue researching in the correct direction. The animation aspect is nothing like what I have found before. I was simply focusing on direct image manipulation of a single image this shows alternatives.

Comment: Excellent. That gives me something to respond to in a way that I hope you find useful!